# Behavior of $GeoLocationCity within a Block

Tags: geodesy

According to the V10 documentation on `$GeoLocation`,

> \$GeoLocationCity gives the city entity for the current setting for \$GeoLocation

And since this is essentially all the documentation has to say about it, I thought that if I were to change the value of `$GeoLocation`, the value of `$GeoLocationCity` would change as well. I have verified that this true when it is done at top level, but I get unexpected and undesirable results when I change `$GeoLocation` within the scope of a `Block`.

Here is where *Mathematica* thinks I am at the start of a session.

```
$GeoLocationCity // FullForm
```

> ```
> Entity["City", List["FarmingtonHills", "Michigan", "UnitedStates"]]
> ```

Now I want to pretend, temporarily, I am in London.

```
Block[{$GeoLocation = GeoPosition @ CityData["London", "Coordinates"]}, 
  Column @ {Here, $GeoLocationCity // FullForm}]
```

> ```
> GeoPosition[{51.5, -0.116667}]
> Entity["City", List["FarmingtonHills", "Michigan", "UnitedStates"]]
> ```

It didn't work. Although `Here` reflects the assignment to `$GeoLocation` in the first argument of `Block`, `$GeoLocationCity` seems oblivious to that assignment.

What's going on here? Why doesn't the `Block` work as I expected it to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suspecting the odd behavior of `$GeoLocationCity` is caused by some sort of caching or memoization mechanism, I did a little spelunking.

---

Code in this section must be evaluated with a fresh kernel.

```
Attributes[$GeoLocationCity] = {Protected};
?? $GeoLocationCity
```

[image: geo-loc-city-1]

```
?? System`Dump`GeoLocationDump`setGeoLocationCity
```

[image: set-geo-loc-city]

```
 $GeoLocationCity // FullForm
```

> ```
> Entity["City", List["FarmingtonHills", "Michigan", "UnitedStates"]]
> ```

```
?? $GeoLocationCity
```

[image: geo-loc-city-2]

---

My spelunking shows that `$GeoLocationCity` looks at `$GeoLocation` only at first time it is evaluated, after which it is memoized. So a solution (or is it a work-around?) is to explicitly call the undocumented function `$GeoLocationCity` calls the first time it is evaluated.

```
Block[{$GeoLocation = GeoPosition@CityData["London", "Coordinates"], 
   $GeoLocationCity},
  System`Dump`GeoLocationDump`setGeoLocationCity[]; 
  Column @ {Here, $GeoLocationCity // FullForm}]
```

> ```
> GeoPosition[{51.5, -0.116667}]
> Entity["City", List["London", "GreaterLondon", "UnitedKingdom"]]
> ```

The global value `$GeoLocationCity` has not been disturbed.

```
$GeoLocationCity // FullForm
```

> ```
> Entity["City", List["FarmingtonHills", "Michigan", "UnitedStates"]]
> ```